# How to force style formatting into child tags of <P>

Tags: css

My main HTML formatting is controlled by the

```
<P>
```

tag.

My application is dynamically constructed HTML using HTML fragments stored in a database, and block of text are encapsulated in

tags, and thus pick up the default CSS styling for the

tags. However sometimes erroneous extra tags get inserted like  tags which will then negate the

styling. The problem is that these extra tags could be anything, so it is difficult to construct a rule for every scenario. So what I need is a CSS rule that will apply to any text within it regardless of other existent tags.

So normal situation:

```
<style>
p {font-family:arial}
</style>

<p>this would render as arial</p>

<p><span>problems here</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family:calibri">problems here definitely, need to have paragraph rules imposed here ie overrule span font rule</span></p>
```

So I would like to know how I can get the paragraph CSS rule to overrule all child tag css rules.

Possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `p {font-family:arial!important}`

Comment: Ok thanks, for this. I was aware of this command. So this is the recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Any tag inside p */
p * {
    font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

If you know specific tag, like span, then

```
p span {
    font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

Comment: OK. Really appreciate this. So this is the recommended approach to this problem? I was sort of aware of the !important attribute.

Comment: Oh, just realised the inclusion of *. Is this a wildcard operator? ie any tag below p

Comment: @SamJolly Usually inline css has the most priority. So to forced it to override you have to use !important.

Comment: @SamJolly Asterisk (*) is used to mark all/any tag.

Answer (score 1):

[inheritvalue reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritvalue)
[Test page](http://jsfiddle.net/x6ftT/3/)

This has the advantage that it will inherit any font properties which are set by the parent element thus p. The !important is only needed when it concerns inline styles to be able to overide it.

*All properties*

```
p * {
  font: inherit !important;
}
```

*Or specifically one property*

```
p * {
  font-family: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: Awarded mark up, as I really appreciate your take on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
p {
    font-family: arial;
}

p * {
    font-family: inherit !important;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/safeer/nUf92/2/)

NOTE: IE 7 or minor versions do not support `inherit` value

Comment: Setting !important also for p element will cause issues when trying to set different styles for paragraphs. You would be forced to use the !important again. For example: p.other-style {font-family: georgia !important;}

Comment: Ok, I understand Sigma's reply, but appreciate Safeer's timely help and fiddle setup hence the markup.

Comment: I agree with Sigma and yes `inherit` is a good way to address this. I'll update this accordingly.